# How do I display a top-ten list, grid or spreadsheet within Nagios?

Tags: nagios, visualization

tldr; I would like to show a list of the ten slowest Apache requests within the past 24 hours.

Long version:

I can modify Apache to include in a custom log the time to required to serve the request and I can also write a shell script to retrieve the ten slowest entries within a defined time interval. The output can be passed on to Nagios via NRPE.

Once Nagios has received it, is there a plugin that allows Nagios to display it as a list? Alternatively, an HTML style table or embedded faux spreadsheet also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off using special tools for this. While this solution might be slightly overkill for you, I used to send all of my messages from NRPE to Splunk as well. Splunk allows you to actually map these things and it is very handy to find patterns and graphing. It has also got some nice dashboard options. (if you need to convince a manager)

It's free up to a certain level and then it gets really expensive.

Comment: We ended up using "special tools" per Lucas' recommendation. We declined to use Splunk due to the price and went with some other solution but I'm going to err on the side of caution and refrain from saying what we did so I don't get accused of astroturfing. It's not hard to Google Splunk's competitors though. :)